# Cancel a Webclient.DownloadFile within a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, background, webclient

Background Info: I have a program running through a list of url; each URL is to be downloaded one at a time but ran in a background thread to maintain UI responsiveness. In order to report progress, I'm using the DownloadFileAsync method. **My problem is that I would like to be able to have a cancel button that would immediately end the download.** My code goes something along the lines of

```
AutoResetEvent autoMobile = new AutoResetEvent(false);
WebClient dclient = new WebClient();

//setup event handlers... for progress, etc...

dclient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(egg.DownloadURL), egg.LocalFilePath);
autoMobile.WaitOne();

//end of DoWork
```

I cannot think of a way or place to insert a loop to check for cancellation pending. I only slightly understand threads and do not fully understand the AutoResetEvent either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `System.Net.WebClient`, it contains a `CancelAsync()` method which should do it for you.  All you should need is a reference to the specific WebClient you want to cancel so your button's click event can call that method.

Mind you, I haven't tested this myself - but that'd be the first thing I try.

Comment: It does indeed free the worker; the idea seemed to have slipped my mind. Thank-you