# Cancel webclient.UploadFileAsync() casue TargetInvocationException error

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using Webclient to upload file and when the user click on abort. I want to cancel the upload, but the file continue to upload until it is completed.  In my abort button, I issued a wc.CancelAsync which cause the form to close and issue a TargetInvocationException was unhandled error at Program.cs

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmUpload());
}
```

Here are portion of my codes

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();  

    private void buttonAbort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wc.CancelAsync();
    }

//Upload code
    try
    {
        wc.UploadFileAsync(Uripath, localPath);                    
        wc.UploadProgressChanged += uploadBarStat;
        wc.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(doneFTP);
    }
```

My question is almost identifical to [Cancel a Webclient.DownloadFile within a BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522244/cancel-a-webclient-downloadfile-within-a-backgroundworker)

What am I missing and what do I need to do in order to cancel the upload smoothly? or trap the exception error?

TIA
Steve

Comment: our code isn't compresible. you use ONE button to cancel and to try upload.(this is what i understand reading your code.This doesn't work because in frist u try to cancel a operation,but these isn't run.

Comment: sorry the "upload code" apply to the upload button. the code above are in sections.

Comment: Update!  figure out the problem. In the upload code, I checked if e.cancel == true and if so, do a "clean up" and return to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a catch to go along with that "try"? Also, wrap the `wc.CancelAsync();` in a try/catch and then run the debugger. Does the `TargetInvocationError` get caught like a normal exception via the catch, or does it still throw an ugly error in the IDE?

If it still throws an ugly error in the IDE, perhaps this post will be of some help:

[Why is TargetInvocationException treated as uncaught by the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658908/why-is-targetinvocationexception-treated-as-uncaught-by-the-ide)

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable boolean:

```
bool inUpload=false;
```

then change value like :

```
    void UploadProgressChanged()
            {
               inUpload=true;
            }

void UploadFileCompleted()
            {
               inUpload=false;
            }
```

and add check in click event:

```
 private void buttonAbort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (inUpload) wc.CancelAsync();
    }
```